# MySQL: referring to a composite key

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns: name, age, address.
I want name and age to be a composite key to refer to an address.

```
Create table usertable (
  name varchar(100) not null, 
  age int not null, 
  address varchar(100) not null,
  constraint addresskey PRIMARY KEY(name,age)
);
```

This works:

```
select * from usertable where (name,age)=('somename',someage);
```

But i would like to do something like:

```
select * from usertable where addresskey=('somename',someage);
```

I get an error when I do this.

Comment: As long as they're dead, this plan will work fine.

Comment: @Strawberry, it's just an simplified example.

Comment: You cannot do what you want.  You have to name the columns explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In that way you want to say that you put the primary key for the addresskey.
1) It's not a good idea to put name and age as primary key because there should be some duplicates.
2) You get an error because the query is wrong because you don't have a field named addresskey and in the query you compare a varchar with 2 fields.

So if you want to do that you can add a field addresskey as an auto_increment field (but pay attention to manage the same address, decide how it could works) and then you can select using addresskey value.